# vuefire dynamic query issues

Tags: vue.js, vuefire

I have an odd issue....

When using dynamic queries with VueFire, the query appears to run and returns data in to an array called customSiteSearch. I can console out the array and see the data there as expected.

The bit that I am struggling with is, when I evaluate the length of the customSiteSearch array after the query has run, it always returns 0 the first time. When I run the function again for a second time it appears to work. What could be the cause of this?

my code:

```
customSiteExists(customSite){
      console.log('starting customSiteExists')
      this.$bindAsArray('customSiteSearch', db.ref('slinksites/').orderByChild('customsite').equalTo(customSite) )
      console.log('search result', this.customSiteSearch)
      console.log(this.customSiteSearch.length)
    },
```

Comment: Does that happen always at the first time of the query?

Comment: Yeh so far... From what I remember